# Boot stuck at random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read, 2 bits of entropy available) Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, linux-kernel, lvm

I downloaded an image backup from ovh, it's a debian8 vps. After downloading it(.raw format) with openstack I imported it into my proxmox with qemu-importdisk <vm_id> . After successfully importing the disk, proxmox recognizes it, I power on the vm, the grub-bootloader shows up, loads the ramdisk but gets stuck here:
[image: boot stuck]

here's the output of booting the same kernel in recovery mode:
[image: boot recovery mode]
it looks like it's trying to boot from a missing partition. So I booted with a live os, mounted the (only) partition of the disk, and ran blkid, here's the output:
[image: blkid description]

Now, given that the uuid is the same of the previous image, just to be sure, I reinstalled the grub bootloader, but the issue persists.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: in the initramfs shell, check `cat /proc/partitions` to see if it was detected at all. otherwise you might have to change disk emulation mode.

Comment: As it turns out, the controller of the previous vps had a raid controller, changing the scsi controller from "VirtIO SCSI" to "MegaRAID SAS 8708EM2" and booting in recovery mode, i was able to log in into the system. Thank you @frostschutz for the precious hint, I was fooled by the fact that with the VirtIO SCSI controller I was able to reach the grub boot loader. *PLEASE NOTE* that once you boot into the system, you might want to take a look at /etc/fstab, to see if there are any partitions that are not present anymore.

Comment: linux should be mostly agnostic to such hardware changes (as long as it's the same platform/architecture). but initramfs is often optimized to only include necessary modules. just to make it boot a little quicker. so if a hardware change happens, it will stop working as necessary modules are unavailable at initramfs stage. sometimes there's a 'fallback' initramfs with all modules you can use instead, but on a server that boots non-interactively, and bootloader not set up to do automagic fallbacks, you're stuck and need to fix things from rescue chroot...